# Japanese wheel mortar

Tags: words, food

What is the Japanese word for a wheel mortar? This is a mortar that is shaped like a boat or a trough, and a wheel with a hole in it through which there is a wooden axle. The operator pushes the wheel back and forth in the trough to grind the material. It is used traditionally used to grind pharmaceuticals, herbs and food ingredients. It looks kind of like this:

[image: herb grinder]

Comment: [薬研](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%96%AC%E7%A0%94)

Comment: @h2so5 Why not post that as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [薬研{やげん}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%96%AC%E7%A0%94) in Japanese.

By the way, I've heard of [薬研堀{やげんぼり}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%96%AC%E7%A0%94%E5%A0%80) but never known 薬研 itself.